# how to display react variable in render function using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

why doesn't 'hidden' get added to the input tag?

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hidden: true };
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.hidden);

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" {this.state ? 'hidden':'';}  />
       <button id="decreaseButton" hidden='true'>-</button>
        <span id="fontSizeSpan" hidden="true">
          {this.props.size}
        </span>
        <button id="increaseButton" hidden="true">
          +
        </button>
        <span id="textSpan">{this.props.text}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here's my html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Font Chooser</title>
    <script src="react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="react/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="FontChooser.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/jsx">

      ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
      <FontChooser min='4' max='40' size='16' text='Fun with React!' bold='false'/>
      </div>,
      document.getElementById('container'))
      ;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want hidden to be a value of the type attribute or the class attribute?

Comment: i just want to add the word hidden to the input tag as it doesn't take any arguments like true or false

Comment: To completely hide it, or just disable it?

Comment: just to hide the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inline styles to hide

```
<input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" style={this.state.hidden ? {display: 'none'} : {} />
```

Or you can use classes to hide

```
<input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" className={this.state.hidden ? classes.hidden : ''} />
```

If you just don't want to render it

```
{!this.state.hidden &&
<input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" />
}
```

Comment: Good answer. He can also put the ternary in the `type` attribute, so `type` is `hidden` or `checkbox`

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type={this.state.hidden ? 'hidden' : 'checkbox'} id="boldCheckbox"  />
```

Comment: doesn't work it adds class='hidden' but i need to add just hidden

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" {...this.state} />
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" hidden={this.state.hidden} />
```

Comment: both works perfectly well
https://codepen.io/dimoff66/pen/zYxOjdb?editors=1010

Comment: @DCR Who "they"? What is "updated post"? What is relation it has to your question and my absolutely precise answer? Strange...

Comment: @DCR You can come by the link to codepen i posted above and see that it works, but if personally for you it doesnt work - bad luck, thank you for question

Comment: your example doesn't reflect the question. move reatDOM.render to the html file and you'll see your answer doesn't work, not even for you.