# Render one of the component that has inside another component according to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm facing an issue of rendering components following a condition. Both of the components have inside the exact component that should be rendered but not displayed.
Both of them are styled with Styled Components.

In my example, I want to display one component when clicking on the other component (footer).
Currently, I have this working:

```
    <footer className={cx(styles.footer, { [styles.hideFooter]: hide })}>
        <StyledAboutContainer>
          <About />
        </StyledAboutContainer>
    </footer>
```

And I want to transform it into a Styled component way and I struggle.
I've tried to do this:

```
     <StyledFooterContainer hide={false}>
        {hide ? StyledHideFooter : StyledFooter}
        <StyledAboutContainer>
          <About />
        </StyledAboutContainer>
    </footer>
```

The CSS of them are:

```
export const StyledFooterContainer = styled.div`
 max-height: 0;
`;

export const StyledFooter = styled.footer`
 background: #EFF0F4;
 color: #6782A4;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 flex-grow: 1;
 max-height: 150px;
 font-size: 10pt;
 transition: .7s ease;
`;

export const StyledHideFooter = styled.div`
 max-height: 0;
`;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to display react variable in render function using ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119351/how-to-display-react-variable-in-render-function-using-ternary-operator)

Comment: doesn't look like, look like something else.

Comment: Why not just _not_ render the footer when hiding it? `!hide && (<footer .... `, or use the ternary and `hide ? null : (<footer ..... `? This is the more idiomatic way of selectively rendering UI in React. Only reason not to that really comes to mind is if you need to keep that footer mounted at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You want to determine which footer component to use before the return statement:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  // Determine the footer component to use
  const FooterComponent = hide ? StyledHideFooter : StyledFooter;

  // Render FooterComponent
  return (
    <StyledFooterContainer>
      <FooterComponent>
        <StyledAboutContainer>
          <About />
        </StyledAboutContainer>
      </FooterComponent>
    </StyledFooterContainer>
  );
};
```

Components are just variables, so you can store them as such.