# How to conditionally hide and show in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

when I click on one div it shows time after that click on another div previously should hide new time will be shown but it doesn't. How is that possible in reactjs?

```
{
  data.length != 0 &&
    data.messages.map(sms => {
      return (
        <li key={sms._id}>
          <div
            className={
              "timestamp " +
              (smsId == sms._id && this.state.hideT ? "block " : "hide ") +
              (sms.smsAuther == "" ? "them-time" : "me-time")
            }
            id=""
          >
            {sms.smsTime}
          </div>
          <div
            className={"sms_li " + (sms.smsAuther == "" ? "them" : "me")}
            onClick={() => this.setState({ hideT: !hideT, smsId: sms._id })}
          >
            <div>{sms.smsContent}</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119351/how-to-display-react-variable-in-render-function-using-ternary-operator/59119499#59119499

Comment: What are you trying to do? your problem statement doesn't make sense. Where is the `click on another div previously` in the code? Do you have css classes for each of these className's? aka `.block {`, `.them {`, `.me {`, `.none {`... etc

Comment: it shows the mobile sms, there are couple of sms for example hello and hye , problem is when i click on hello hidden time will show after that when i click on hye previous open time will hide but time of hye is not show after that i click on hey it shows thats my issue

Comment: If I was going to make a chat messaging application, and was going to let the user click on the message to see its timestamp. Clicking on another message moves the last selection to the one that was just clicked... [**I would probably do something like this**](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-murdock-8jh8o). Is this what you wanted? I can write it up as a solution if so :)

Comment: I got the solution, thanks for sharing your thoughts

Comment: you should post it as an answer and then accept that answer so this question is closed out :)